# Using a dictionary to perform basic CRUD operations and getting an sqlite syntax error

Tags: c#

I'm learning SQL and decided to use a data structure I've never used before, a dictionary, to create some methods to perform basic CRUD operations. The first method that I am working on is a method to delete a person given a table name and a dictionary containing the strings to be used in the SQL statement. Here is the code.

```
class QueryBuilder
{
        public void DeleteMemer(string tableName, Dictionary<string, string> columns)
        {
            var sqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand($"delete from '{tableName}' where {columns.Keys} = '{columns.Values}'", connection);
            sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}

class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DBManagerSQLite memes = new DBManagerSQLite("SqliteDataBase.db");
            QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(memes.connection);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //------------------DELETE TEST------------------
            dict.Add("Memer", "Ryan");
            queryBuilder.DeleteMemer("Memers", dict);
        }
}
```

Edited for clarity. I get a run time error on the sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() line. I suspect this is because of the dictionary I am using. I previously was using all my CRUD operations with simple strings but decided to change it and use a dictionary. I think I am not understand how to use a dictionary in this way. If I remove the dictionary and just hard code strings, the methods work just fine.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: What is the problem/error you're facing?

Comment: I updated it for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This can lead to SQL injection - I'd suggest you sanitize input using `SqlParameter`
2. When injected like this, `{columns.Keys}` will transfrom to something like `System...ICollection`, which is definetely not the column name.
3. It would be good if you clarified the question. Assuming the problem is exception on syntax error:

You can iterate over key value pairs to create a `WHERE` clause for your query.

**Example (without sanitizing!):**

```
var whereClause = string.Join(" OR ", columns.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key} = '{kvp.Value}'")); // join with AND to create more restrictive query
var sqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand($"delete from '{tableName}' where {whereClause}", connection);
```

**UPD**:

Apart from question, why do you try to use the db that way? It's fairly easy to implement code-first EF context, and you will get, along with simplicity, compile-time checks on your queries. And only once you will need more speed, you can switch to any micro-ORM and carefully optimize performance-critical queries

Comment: I actually was using SqlParameters, but commented it out because it was throwing some errors and decided to focus on this error first. I updated the post to add more clarity.

Comment: 1. Well, I'd recommend to switch back to `SqlParameter`s and fix errors with them, as it's more secure way; 2. example in my answer is what you can put in `DeleteMemer` (prior to `sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` )